# Path not found error when trying to access sharepoint

Tags: vba, sharepoint, excel

I am using this code to loop through the files in sharepoint using excel VBA. This code is working fine when I am using the local drive path. But when I replace the path with my sharepoint path, I am getting an error saying 'Path Not Found' at fs.GetFolder

Please kindly advice

Code I am using is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim folder As Variant
Dim f As File
Dim fs As New FileSystemObject
Dim fs1 As New OLEObject
Dim RowCtr As Integer
Dim FPath As String
Dim wb As Workbook
FPath = "my URL"
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
RowCtr = 1
Set folder = fs.GetFolder(FPath)
'<=Variable Location
For Each f In folder.Files
   Cells(RowCtr, 1).Value = f.Name
   RowCtr = RowCtr + 1
Next f
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you using a http path, or a webdav path?  http isn't going to work...

Comment: i tried using http path
example path: "http://path/more path/foldername"

I even tried giving path as "\\path\more path\foldername"

Both are not working

Comment: If you only have http access then you can't use the filesystemobject to loop though a folder like that.  Maybe there's a sharepoint'y way to do this, but I'm not familiar with that platform.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to map sharepoint to a Windows drive letter, as outlined in [SharePoint StackExchange](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/43048). Once it's mapped you'll be able to open as a local drive path.